# Connection one-form and suppressed indices

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading Sean Carroll's [notes on GR](http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/grnotes/), which states (Page 91):

> Using our freedom to suppress indices on differential forms, we can write the defining relations for these two tensors as:
>   $$
> T^a = de^a + \omega^a_{~~b}\wedge e^b
> $$

Does he mean that we can suppress the tensorial indices such that $\omega^a_{~~b} = \omega^a_{\mu b}dx^\mu$?

Taking the definition of the connection one-form:
$$
\omega^a_{~~b} = \Gamma^a_{bc}\hat{\theta}^c~~~~~~~~\text{where}~~~~~\hat{\theta}^c = e^c_\mu dx^\mu
$$
Writing in this in components (if I use the definition above) gives:
$$
\omega^a_{\mu b} = \Gamma^a_{bc}e^c_\mu
$$

Is this correct? The definition he gives is the notes (eqn 3.132) is 
$$
\omega^a_{\mu b} = e^a_\nu e^\lambda_b\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\lambda} - e^\lambda_b\partial_\mu e^a_\lambda
$$

The first term basically agrees with mine, but I can't see how to find the second term.

Comment: Where did you get the definition of the connection one-form, specifically the equation $\omega^a{}_b = \Gamma^a_{bc} \hat{\theta}^c$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_form#Example:_The_Levi-Civita_connection for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion here seems to be about notation. The symbols in Wikipedia and in Carroll mean different things altogether.

Let's backtrack a bit, and put this in more general grounds: given a connection $\nabla$ on a vector bundle $E$, and a local frame $e_k$, the connection can be expressed locally by

$\nabla e_j= de_j+\omega^i_j e_i$

where $\omega^i_j$ is a one form for all $i,j$, i.e., $\omega=(\omega^i_j)$ is a one form with values in the endomorphisms of $E$; we call $\omega$ the connection one form (despite it not being globally defined. When a gauge transformation $g$ is applied, you can verify that the transformation law for the connection one-form is

$\omega \mapsto g\omega g^{-1}+g^{-1}dg$

This applies equally well both when $g$ is an actual gauge transformation, or just a change of frame.

Now, given a chart in a Riemannian manifold, the Levi-Civita connection on the tangent bundle in each coordinate patch is defined by the formula above, i.e.,

$\nabla e_j = de_j + \Gamma_{jk}^i e_i$

when $e_j$ is the differential of the coordinates. Equivalently, there is an induced connection on the cotangent bundle. Let $\theta^j$ the the form dual to $e_j$, and write the induced connection as

$\nabla \theta^j = d\theta^j+\omega^j_i \theta^i$

Then, you get the formula in wikipedia.

Now, Carroll is doing a completely different thing. In fact, his $\theta_j$ are not even differential forms, but rather a different frame for the tangent bundle, related to a coordinate frame by $\theta_i=e_i^j e_j$. The formula he derives, then, is not a formula for the dual connection, but for the gauge-transformed connection, which is indeed as he writes. In fact, you you can just plug the relation between the $\theta_i$ and $e_j$ into the equation I wrote above (or read the pages before the one you cited, where he deduces the formula.)

Finally, related to your first question, by "freedom to suppress indices" he does indeed mean that he's going to suppress $\omega_i^j=\omega_{ik}^j dx^k$. This is precisely what I did above, but just mentioning that $\omega_i^j$ was a one form, but not expanding it in a basis.